# Delete a folder in SSH

Tags: ssh

I have a folder that I'd like to delete that is located in httpdocs:
The folder is named: /content/

/var/www/vhosts/webiste/httpdocs/

If i use the CD command to access /httpdocs/ and I'm in that folder, can is use the command:

-rf /content/

Or do I need to use the full directory
e.g -rf /var/www/vhosts/webiste/content/

I just wanted to clarify in case this would delete every folder on the server called content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use /content.. it's an absolute path.

use just **rm -rf content** when the *content* folder is inside */var/www/vhosts/webiste/httpdocs/* and your current working directory is */var/www/vhosts/webiste/httpdocs/*